# JavaScript calendar to display date as DD/MM/YYYY?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have very shallow knowledge of JavaScript, and need to provide a calendar to let users choose a date.

jQuery DatePicker looks nice, but [the sample](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization) doesn't format date as DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYYI.

Does someone know how to get it to work as planned, of it can't, which other light JavaScript solution is available that can?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the date format examples at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
});
```

Comment: For me this method only allows to change month. Can't select year. Is there any way to select year directly? My intention is to select date of birth